# Using the figure of fire in describing your fear of something

Tags: grammar

What's the right way of using the figure of fire in describing how you are afraid of something?

> those algebra tests that I was scared of **like of fire**
>
> those algebra tests that I was scared of **as of fire**
>
> those algebra tests that I was scared of **as fire**
>
> those algebra tests that I was scared of **like fire**

Comment: This is looking a lot like someone's grammar homework! I'll take what's behind **Door #4** (like fire).

Comment: Please consider supporting the proposal for a StackExchange site for English Language Learners:[http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners)

Comment: Those algebra tests scared me as much as any fire could.

Comment: How about: "Those algebra tests scared me like fire!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All four alternatives are basically awful. Native English speakers wouldn't normally use this construction, because it's too unwieldy. No "relational conjunctions" sound natural here.

I don't know any *"as fearful/frightened/afraid/etc. as a/the **xxxx**"* that are particularly widespread across region or era. Certainly *fear of **fire*** has no special significance in normal speech.

So OP has some work to do constructing a sentence to convey his intended meaning - otherwise the listener is likely to end up thinking *"Why is he talking about **fire**?"*. I'd suggest maybe...

> Those algebra tests scare me like [the fires of hell!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fires_of_Hell)

Still in the Christian tradition, a more "idiomatic" fear that comes to mind is...

> Those algebra tests [put the fear of **God** into me!"](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/put-the-fear-of-god-into-you)

Comment: Those algebra tests scare the hell out of me.

Comment: @David Wallace: Yes, that's another common one. But as with *put the fear of God into me*, we're drifting some way from OP's original wish to equate his fear of the tests with his fear of fire.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd say, "those algebra tests that I was **as** scared of as fire", but since you can only pick one of those four I'll go with the fourth one.

Comment: But would it not sound then as if I was comparing myself to fire?

Comment: @brilliant: in a word, no.

Comment: @Marthaª - It's because of having 'of' in there, right?

Answer (score 0):

Most euphonious would be "I feared those algebra tests like fire."